# symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 after changing Xcode 11

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I updated the Xcode to 11.

And I found this linker error.

For simulator or device, same result.

Maybe this is related to google library.

The code are generated by `flutter`

does anyone helps??

```
Ld /Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner normal x86_64
    cd /Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -target x86_64-apple-ios8.0-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.6.sdk -L/Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/ios/Flutter -F/Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore -F/Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -F/Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstallations -F/Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleDataTransport -F/Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities -F/Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC -F/Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/audioplayers -F/Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/device_info -F/Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/devicelocale -F/Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_admob -F/Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_core -F/Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb -F/Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/path_provider -F/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/ios/Pods/../Flutter -F/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/ios/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current -F/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/ios/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -F/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/ios/Flutter -filelist /Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.swiftmodule -framework Flutter -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Runner.app-Simulated.xcent -framework Pods_Runner -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/whitebear/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fmdqnsejacqtieemqnlzypktvywr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_admob(FLTRequestFactory.o)
  "_GULLogBasic", referenced from:
      _FIRLogBasic in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_GULSetLoggerLevel", referenced from:
      _FIRSetLoggerLevel in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADExtras", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_admob(FLTRequestFactory.o)
  "_GULLoggerInitializeASL", referenced from:
      ___FIRLoggerInitializeASL_block_invoke in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_GULLoggerEnableSTDERR", referenced from:
      ___FIRLoggerInitializeASL_block_invoke in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADInterstitial", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_admob(FLTMobileAd.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_admob(FLTMobileAd.o)
  "_GULLoggerRegisterVersion", referenced from:
      ___FIRLoggerInitializeASL_block_invoke in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADMobileAds", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_admob(FLTMobileAd.o)
  "_GADAdSizeFromCGSize", referenced from:
      -[FLTFirebaseAdMobPlugin callLoadBannerAdWithId:channel:call:result:] in firebase_admob(FLTFirebaseAdMobPlugin.o)
  "_GULLoggerForceDebug", referenced from:
      ___FIRLoggerInitializeASL_block_invoke in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape", referenced from:
      -[FLTFirebaseAdMobPlugin callLoadBannerAdWithId:channel:call:result:] in firebase_admob(FLTFirebaseAdMobPlugin.o)
  "_kGADAdLoaderAdTypeUnifiedNative", referenced from:
      -[FLTNativeAd loadWithAdUnitId:targetingInfo:] in firebase_admob(FLTMobileAd.o)
  "_GULResetLogger", referenced from:
      _FIRResetLogger in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADAdLoader", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_admob(FLTMobileAd.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULAppEnvironmentUtil", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseCore(FIRApp.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseCore(FIRBundleUtil.o)
  "_GULIsLoggableLevel", referenced from:
      _FIRIsLoggableLevel in FirebaseCore(FIRLogger.o)
  "_kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait", referenced from:
      -[FLTFirebaseAdMobPlugin callLoadBannerAdWithId:channel:call:result:] in firebase_admob(FLTFirebaseAdMobPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRewardBasedVideoAd", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_admob(FLTRewardedVideoAdWrapper.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: The 1 and best solution which always worked for me in this type of error - is remove that external library then install again.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.64.0.zip from google

and copy `GoogleMobileAds.framework` to ios/Frameworks manually.

then, Targets `Runner` -> `Build Phases` -> `Link Binary with Libraries` -> add(+) `GoogleMobileAds` file under `GoogleMobileAds.framwork` folder'

I guess root cause is somehow `cocoapods` doesn't work correctly.

So I added framework manually, then solved.